# One Table to Another Table Insert only check particular field Duplication

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm inserting values into the table which already have row of values in it named as `TestDueAlert`  and another table have the same columns name and table row of values in it named as `temp`,

```
INSERT INTO TestDueAlert(Name,EmailId,TankNo,TankType,CertificateType,TestedBy,TestDate,ExpiryDate,NoOfSnooze)
    SELECT[Name],[EmailId],[TankNo],[TankType],[CertificateType],[TestedBy],[TestDate],[ExpiryDate],[NoOfSnooze] 
    FROM @temp  
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [Name],[EmailId],[TankNo],[TankType],[CertificateType],[TestedBy],[TestDate],[ExpiryDate],[NoOfSnooze] 
    FROM TestDueAlert
```

Now how do I check and insert values from `temp` table to `TestDueAlert` by checking particular field duplication and get inserted?

Here the TankNo field should not allow duplication record in TestDueAlert.

Here is the Table script i created,

```
CREATE TABLE  TestDueAlert(TAID  INT NOT NULL,Name NVARCHAR(500),EmailId VARCHAR(250),TankNo VARCHAR(250),TankType VARCHAR(500),CertificateType VARCHAR(500),
    TestedBy VARCHAR(500),TestDate DateTime,ExpiryDate DateTime,NoOfSnooze INT);
```

Comment: Could you post more the script Create TestDueAlert table?

Comment: @Tomato32 Now added

Comment: As I see the Create script above, you must insert data for TAID column or modify this column is identity, my friend.

Comment: @Tomato32 but the temp table doesn't have TAID ,here i only insert values without TAID

Comment: TAID column should be identity, so it will insert the automatic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way which makes your intent very clear is to use `not exists`:

```
-- insert rows into testDueAlert only if the TankNo value does not already exist
insert TestDueAlert
(
   Name,
   EmailId,
   TankNo,
   TankType,
   CertificateType,
   TestedBy,
   TestDate,
   ExpiryDate,
   NoOfSnooze
)
select   t.[Name],
         t.[EmailId],
         t.[TankNo],
         t.[TankType],
         t.[CertificateType],
         t.[TestedBy],
         t.[TestDate],
         t.[ExpiryDate],
         t.[NoOfSnooze] 
from     @temp t
where    not exists
         (
            select * from TestDueAlert where TankNo = t.TankNo
         )
```